# How to upgrade 2 years old server?

Tags: memory, hardware, central-processing-unit, nic, high-load

Two years ago I bought a server with the following characteristics:

- **Platform:** Supermicro X9SRi-F Motherboard
- **RAM:** 8*8GB ECC 2133 DDR4 Reg (64GB)
- **CPU:** Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 v3 @ 2.60GHz 10 cores
- **SSD:** SSD 100GB SATA III Intel DC S3700 MLC- HET 2,5"" Enterprise series (Read/Write Command Rate (KIOPS) Peak, 4KB 75/19) Mainstream Endurance
- **NIC:** Mellanox ConnectX-3 2 port 10GE

The price for such server was about 6k USD.
Now I would like to buy a new one with better specs and I have about 10k USD to spend. 
I use this server for HFT (high frequency trading), so network perfomance is crucial.

Considering two years passed, what are my options on component replacing/upgading: top shelf NICs, fastest RAM, CPU and platforms?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning

Answer (score 2):

I would start monitoring the server load on various domains and find the bottleneck first, before start spending.